# Custom normalisation for spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy

I'm using `en_core_web_sm` and I'm trying to adapt it to my corpus.
I've adjusted the tokenizer and now it generates the tokens as required.

For our corpus, it is important to process the `end of line` token separately. For this purpose, I would like to do a few things for this token:

- override normalized form by replacing `/n` with something like `[EOL]` in token.norm_
- keep part of speech as `SPACE` for proper parsing in the future

I saw that there is a `norm_exceptions.py` file with all the exceptions for the normalization. But I cannot figure out how to force my `Language` object to use an amended configuration for normalization.

How to use custom norm_exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. 
I ended up writing a custom Tokenizer that makes sure that all /n characters are separate tokens. The same for spaces.

Since vectorization algorithm is not clear and see it like a black box, we ended up writing our own vectorization. We didn't use spacy native vectors.